# Extraer datos de tabla de una bbdd a otra

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

Necesito extraer unos datos de algunas tablas y poder guardarlos en otras tablas dentro de una base de datos distinta. Y esto debe ocurrir cada cierto tiempo para actualizar los registros de la tabla destino (es la que debo usar).

La verdad es que no sé como debo proceder en este caso. La web la hice con Laravel y esta usa una base de datos Mysql con la estructura necesaria para su funcionamiento. La cosa es que esta base de datos se llena con datos de otra base de datos ajena.

Estaba pensando en una api para extraer los datos y hacer los updates a cada tabla manualmente con laravel, pero es lo que se me ha ocurrido.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta para proceder? ¿La forma que se me ocurrió está bien o mal?

Comment: Hecha un vistaso aqui, igual y te das una idea. https://php-etl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Pues esto es posible en laravel.

1º Debes configurar tu archivo en `config > database.php`

```
'connections' => [

     'mysql'      => [
         'driver'     => 'mysql',
         'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
         'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
         'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
         'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
         'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
         'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
         'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
         'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
         'prefix' => '',
         'strict' => true,
         'engine' => null,
     ],

    'yoursql'  => [
         'driver'     => 'mysql',
         'host' => env('YOURSQL_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
         'port' => env('YOURSQL_PORT', '3306'),
         'database' => env('YOURSQL_DATABASE', 'forge'),
         'username' => env('YOURSQL_USERNAME', 'forge'),
         'password' => env('YOURSQL_PASSWORD', ''),
         'unix_socket' => env('YOURSQL_SOCKET', ''),
         'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
         'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
         'prefix' => '',
         'strict' => true,
         'engine' => null,
     ],
],
```

Una vez configuradas ambas bases de datos, si te fijas tienen 2 nombres distintos.

```
-mysql
-yoursql
```

Recuerda configurar en el archivo ENV

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=base_de_datos_principal
DB_USERNAME=usuario_base_datos_principal
DB_PASSWORD=pass_usuario_base_datos_principal


YOURSQL_CONNECTION=mysql
YOURSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
YOURSQL_PORT=3306
YOURSQL_DATABASE=base_de_datos_secundaria
YOURSQL_USERNAME=usuario_base_datos_secundaria
YOURSQL_PASSWORD=pass_usuario_base_datos_secundaria
```

Una vez configuradas las bases de datos, debes tener en cuenta que:

-Cuando no especifiques a laravel que conexión debe usar, por defecto usará la primera base de datos "mysql"

Ahora solo debes especificar la conexión 
`::connection('yoursql')->where()....`

También, si un modelo fuera a utilizar prácticamente solo la 2ª base de datos, es mas práctico indicar al modelo que conexión debe realizar, que especificar en cada consulta la base de datos.

Esto puedes hacerlo en el modelo

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TUMODELO extends Model {

    // Conexion que va a usar este modelo
    protected $connection = 'yoursql';

    ...

}
```

Ahora, simplemente especifica la conexión para extraer los datos.

Y después le especificas la conexión para subir los datos. "voila", conexión múltiple.